# gem from rubygems installs in gems folder, but same gem from github installs in bundler/gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, rbenv, gemfile

I have a small sample ruby file and Gemfile that I am using to diagnose an odd inconsistency that I get when using git as a source. When I run
`ruby color.rb` I get the following error.

```
$ ruby color.rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from color.rb:1:in `<main>'
        1: from /Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require': cannot load such file -- colorize (LoadError)
```

#### Gemfile

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'colorize', :git => 'https://github.com/fazibear/colorize', :ref => '6f1b02342b1c6f45648e5203218c466dc7642125'
```

#### Color.rb

```
require 'colorize'

puts "This is blue".colorize(:blue)
```

### Issue

From what I can tell, gems from github that I specify in my Gemfile in this manner...

```
gem 'colorize', :git => 'https://github.com/fazibear/colorize', :ref => '6f1b02342b1c6f45648e5203218c466dc7642125'
```

...and installed using `bundle install`, will be installed in this directory

`/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bundler/gems`

However, gems from rubygems that I specify in my Gemfile in this manner...

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'colorize', '0.7.3'
```

...and also installed using `bundle install`, will be installed in this directory

`/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems`

I am just using colorize as an example, but this is behaving the same with any other gem.

I want to know how I can get all my gems I source directly from github whether by branch or by ref to be installed in the `2.5.0/gems` folder rather than the `2.5.0/bundler/gems` directory.

The reason for this is that whenever I run my code it will *never* use the gems in the `2.5.0/bundler/gems` directory and only run from the `2.5.0/gems`directory. I suppose an alternate valid solution could also explain how to get my project to use the gems in the `2.5.0/bundler/gems` directory, but the main issue is that when using github as a source it installs the gems in a different directory as the one my project gets its gems from.

### Environment Info

```
$ rbenv version
2.5.1 (set by /Users/<user>/.rbenv/version)
```

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

Note: At this moment I have the gem installed with `gem 'colorize', '0.7.3'` in my Gemfile

```
$ bundle info colorize
  * colorize (0.7.3)
        Summary: Add color methods to String class
        Homepage: http://github.com/fazibear/colorize
        Path: /Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/colorize-0.7.3
```

```
$ gem which colorize
/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/colorize-0.7.3/lib/colorize.rb
```

```
$ gem environment gempath
/Users/<user>/.gem/ruby/2.5.0:/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
```

```
$ ruby -e 'puts Gem.default_dir'
/Users/<user>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
```

```
$ gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.1.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/<user>>/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/<user>>/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
     - /Users/<user>>/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin
     - /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec
     - /Users/<user>>/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools
     - /Users/<user>>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
     - /Users/<user>>/Library/Android/sdk/tools
     - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
     - /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Users/<user>>/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools
     - /Users/<user>>/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
     - /Users/<user>>/Library/Android/sdk/tools
     - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-13.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin
     - /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/shims
     - /Users/<user>>/.rbenv/bin
```

Comment: _"I want to know how I can get all my gems I source directly from github whether by branch or by ref to be installed in the 2.5.0/gems folder rather than the 2.5.0/bundler/gems directory."_ Why?

Comment: Because my project will not use the gems in the bundler/gems directory, it only uses the gems in the /gems directory

Comment: Explain in detail the actual problem you're having.

Comment: Whenever I run my project it will never use the gems in the 2.5.0/bundler/gems directory and only run from the 2.5.0/gemsdirectory, however I want to use a specific version of the gem from github and when I use github as a source my project won't use it because it is being installed in the 2.5.0/bundler/gems directory, whereas a gem that is from rubygems will be installed in the directory that my project is using which is just the 2.5.0/gems directory.

Comment: _"run my project"_ is not a detailed explanation. Provide a DETAILED explanation of the problem in the post body, please. See [mre].

Comment: Okay, I modified the body of the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using bundler and a Gemfile in your app but not invoking your app with bundler, so when you call `require 'colorize'` it doesn't work because only bundler can tell the app where to find the gem.

Your simplest solution is to invoke your app with bundler:

```
bundle exec ruby color.rb
```

Comment: I cannot believe how simple this was, I used to use bundle exec and I forgot. Thanks.